# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, string, pandas

My `pandas` `DataFrame` looks like following. I am trying to remove `'$'` and `','` from my `income` column and then apply on my original *dataframe*. so I created below function. However, it is giving me error Saying `"str" object has no attribute "str".`

Any suggestion on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

*Note:* I am new to python so please provide explanation.

**My Dataframe:**

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(
     {'Name': ['a', 'b','c','d'],
     'income': ['$1', '$2,000','$10,000','$140,000']})
```

**My Function:**

```
def column_replace(x):
    return x.str.replace('$', '').str.replace(',','').apply(lambda x: column_replace(x))
```

Comment: Just `x.replace` not `x.str.replace`

Comment: Can you add the code that calls `column_replace`?  It looks like that is function you are calling with column of `df1` as the argument, which would suggest one solution.  However, if you intend it to be called with `df1` itself as the argument, that would suggest a different solution, so it's important to make the distinction in your post.

Comment: Just realized that..made correction. Thanks!

Comment: Adding onto what PaSTE said, why is there a need to recursively call `column_replace()`?

Comment: I am trying to replace my original dataframe column with No '$ 'and ','

Comment: @Loocid.. I tried x.replace ; however my income column remained unchanged. No '$' and ',' were removed

Comment: You should have used `x.replace('$', '', inplace=True)` because `replace` by default does not change the original column but creates a copy of it. But indeed `x.str.replace` is the method that you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [23]: df1
Out[23]: 
  Name    income
0    a        $1
1    b    $2,000
2    c   $10,000
3    d  $140,000

In [24]: cols_to_change = ['income']

In [25]: for col in cols_to_change:
    ...:     df1[col] = df1[col].str.replace('[$,]', '')
    ...: 

In [26]: df1
Out[26]: 
  Name  income
0    a       1
1    b    2000
2    c   10000
3    d  140000
```

Comment: What if I have multiple columns in my dataframe that contains $ and ,. How should I approach in removing them ?

Comment: see my updated example. i.e. you could make a list of the columns to change, and loop over them as in my example.