# Drop columns contains certain strings while reading data : python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading .txt files in a directory and want to drop columns that contains some certain string.

```
for file in glob.iglob(files + '.txt', recursive=True):
    
    cols = list(pd.read_csv(file, nrows =1))
    
    df=pd.read_csv(file,header=0, skiprows=0, skipfooter=0, usecols =[i for i in cols if i.str.contains['TRIVIAL|EASY']==False])
```

when I do this I'm getting

> df=pd.read_csv(file,header=0, skiprows=0, skipfooter=0, usecols =[i for i >in cols if i.str.contains['PASS']==True])
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Which part I need tp fix I could not figured it out ?

[select columns based on columns names containing a specific string in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643506/select-columns-based-on-columns-names-containing-a-specific-string-in-pandas)

[drop column based on a string condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383886/drop-column-based-on-a-string-condition)

[AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191821/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-str)

[Drop multiple columns that end with certain string in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060217/drop-multiple-columns-that-end-with-certain-string-in-pandas)

Comment: 1. Never, ever, ever, ever use `if something==False`, read pep8. 2. The trouble with your code is that `cols` is already a list of strings, each element is a string, so a string does not have a string method. Change `i.str.contains['TRIVIAL|EASY']` to `i not in 'TRIVIAL|EASY'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without reading the header separately you would pass a callable to `usecols`. Check whether `'EASY'` or `'TRIVIAL'` are not in the column name.

```
exclu = ['EASY', 'TRIVIAL']  # Any substring in this list excludes a column 
usecols = lambda x: not any(substr in x for substr in exclu)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=usecols)

print(df)
   HARD  MEDIUM
0     2       4
1     6       8
2     1       1
```

---

#### Sample Data: `test.csv`

```
TRIVIAL,HARD,EASYfoo,MEDIUM
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
1,1,1,1
```

Comment: I want to drop them!

Comment: Thanks for your answer too!

Comment: @Alexander did this answer work ? if so this should be ideal answer as it doesn't rely on any other library.

Comment: @ALozz The only diffuculty with your code is that tracking col names if there are many to drop. This syntax is little bit limited for that case I think `Lambda x: not ('EASY' in x or 'TRIVIAL' in x)`

Comment: @Alexander I updated it. Now you just need to provide a list of the substrings you check for and the list comprehension creates the logic. You're going to need to type them out anyway in the `regex` so now they should be comparable.

Answer (score 4):

few issues in your code, first you are using `str.contains` on the whole dataframe not the columns, secondly the str contains cannot be used on a list.

using regex

```
import re

cols = pd.read_csv(file, nrows =1)

cols_to_use = [i for i in cols.columns if not re.search('TRIVIAL|EASY',i)] 


df=pd.read_csv(file,header=0, skiprows=0, skipfooter=0, usecols  =cols_to_use)
```

Comment: I got the error saying     `cols_to_use = [i for i in cols.columns if not re.match('PASS')]

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns' `

Comment: @Alexander remove `list` from your call sorry missed that - will update answer

Comment: No problem. Also, I think we need to use something like `re.findall('TRIVIAL|EASY')` to drop columns contains those strings ?

Comment: @Alexander `re.search` sorry terrible answer on my side, didn't test it all.

Comment: Yes I know the problem is not reproducible. I just did `cols_to_use = [i for i in cols.columns if not re.search('TRIVIAL|EASY')] ` but got `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns' ` then removed `columns` from `cols` and used only `cols` but then got `TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'`

Comment: ok I thin I solved the issue. It should be `cols_to_use = [i for i in cols if not re.search('PASS',i)] ` :)